# How can I do two joins by Laravel relationships?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Here is my table structure:

```
// roles
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | admin |
| 2  | stuff |
+----+-------+

//pages
+----+---------------------+
| id |         path        |
+----+---------------------+
| 1  | users/list          |
| 2  | users/list/paginate |
| 3  | users/make          |
| 4  | posts/add           |
| 5  | posts/edit          |
+----+---------------------+

page_role
+---------+----------+
| page_id | role_id  |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 1        |
| 1       | 2        |
| 1       | 3        |
| 1       | 4        |
| 1       | 5        |
| 2       | 4        |
| 2       | 5        |
+---------+----------+
```

All I'm trying to do is getting all pages for each role. How can I do that by using relationships in Laravel?

---

Here is my current workaround by pure SQL:

```
SELECT p.* FROM roles r
INNER JOIN page_role  pr on r.id = pr.role_id
INNER JOIN pages      p  on p.id = pr.page_id
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Comment: I can see you upvote answers to your questions (even not helpful ones). Any reason you don't upvote my answers? Maybe your feedback could help me to improve the quality of the answers or maybe I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the [`belongsToMany()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) relationship in `Role` model first:

```
public function pages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Page::class);
}
```

Then, to get all pages for each role use the [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method:

```
$rolesWithPages = Role::with('pages')->get();
```

Then you'll be able to iterate over roles and pages for each role:

```
@foreach ($rolesWithPages as $role)
    Role: {{ $role->name }}<br>
    @foreach ($role->pages as $page)
        Page: {{ $page->title }}<br>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I add `where()` clause to this? `$rolesWithPages = Role::with('pages')->get();` *(I want to apply that where on the `roles` table)*

Comment: @stack if it's for the roles table, just add it like this `Role::with('pages')->where('status', 1)->get()`

Comment: You know, I'm really confused, every time I encounter with a new thing, `belongsToMany`, `belongsTo`, `hasOne`, `hasMany`, `manyToMany` and etc ..! Is there any list of all those things?

Comment: @stack check out the docs. The relationships are very well explained there https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Comment: Ok, and as my last question about this topic, is there any difference between `hasMany` and `belongsToMany`?

Comment: @stack yes, they're totally different. Check the docs to understand how each of those relationships works.

Comment: Ok, I will take a look at the docs to see the different, but you (as a Laravel fan) shoud know, Laravel is shit in naming.